# Setup JHipster and Okta

Tags: jhipster, okta

I setup and sucessfully run jhipster with OKta but when I login my account only having ROLE_USER.How can I added ROLE_ADMIN for my account.I add ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN like instruction -

> Create a ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER group (Users > Groups > Add Group)
>   and add users to them. You can use the account you signed up with, or
>   create a new user (Users > Add Person). Navigate to API >
>   Authorization Servers, click the Authorization Servers tab and edit
>   the default one. Click the Claims tab and Add Claim. Name it “groups”
>   or “roles”, and include it in the ID Token. Set the value type to
>   “Groups” and set the filter to be a Regex of .*.

Comment: Did you create a group called ROLE_ADMIN and add your user to it?

Comment: yes.I did.you can see here https://ibb.co/isb37x